# Split one column data into multiple columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

In my oracle query I am using like below for retrieving the records and the result looks like this -

```
SELECT columnC
     , LISTAGG(r.columnA,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY r.columnB) AS Test_sensor
  FROM tableA
 GROUP BY columnC
```

Currently the output looks like below -

```
ColumnC  |  Test_Sensor
=============================
Z12345   |  20,30,40,50,60,70
```

But I want this data to be displayed as below -

```
ColumnC  |  Test_Sensor1 |  Test_Sensor2 |   Test_Sensor3  |  Test_Sensor4
==========================================================================
Z12345   |  20           |   30          |    40           |  50
```

Please help me on this

Thanks
Kranthi RTR

Comment: Do you know that there will always be 6 test sensor columns?  In any case, what you want to do is called "pivoting".  If the number of columns varies, it is a dynamic pivot, and you need to use pl/sql to get the results.

Comment: Hi Gordan, Thanks for reply, Could you please let me know pivot syntax like how I can place that with LISTAGG

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PIVOT` (and do not need to use `LISTAGG`):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75bacf/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA ( ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC ) AS
  SELECT 20, 'A', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 30, 'B', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 40, 'C', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 50, 'D', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 60, 'E', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 70, 'F', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
from (
  SELECT columnA,
         columnC,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY columnC ORDER BY columnB ) AS rn
  FROM   tableA
) a
PIVOT ( MAX( columnA ) FOR rn IN (
  1 AS test_sensor1,
  2 AS test_sensor2,
  3 AS test_sensor3,
  4 AS test_sensor4
) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75bacf/2/0)**:

```
| COLUMNC | TEST_SENSOR1 | TEST_SENSOR2 | TEST_SENSOR3 | TEST_SENSOR4 |
|---------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|  Z12345 |           20 |           30 |           40 |           50 |
```

**Query 2**:

You can do it using `LISTAGG` but it is much, much less efficient than using `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT ColumnC,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '[^,]+', 1, 1 ) AS test_sensor1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '[^,]+', 1, 2 ) AS test_sensor2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '[^,]+', 1, 3 ) AS test_sensor3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '[^,]+', 1, 4 ) AS test_sensor4
FROM   (
  SELECT ColumnC,
         LISTAGG( ColumnA, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ColumnB )
           AS test_sensor
  FROM   TableA
  GROUP BY ColumnC
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75bacf/2/1)**:

```
| COLUMNC | TEST_SENSOR1 | TEST_SENSOR2 | TEST_SENSOR3 | TEST_SENSOR4 |
|---------|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|  Z12345 |           20 |           30 |           40 |           50 |
```

Comment: Thanks MT0, I have used LISTAGG for displaying the 6 rows data into one column cell. I want to achieve the splitting when LISTAGG is available only

Comment: @KranthiRtr What do you mean by "when `LISTAGG` is available only"? If you want extra columns then just add them to the `PIVOT`'s `FOR` clause.

Comment: I mean by using LISTAGG can we not achieve it?

Comment: @KranthiRtr You can but I would not as it is much less performant.

Comment: If i want to use SUBSTR, can I use this in LISTAGG? If yes how can i use it

Comment: @KranthiRtr You have not described what you want to do with `SUBSTR` and I am not going to continually update the answer for an ever growing list of changing requirements. If you want to use `SUBSTR` then please read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks so much MT0, that really helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go with LISTAGG, there is a caveat with LISTAGG in that it ignores NULL values.  Are you sure your columnA will ALWAYS have data?  If, say, test_sensor2 is NULL, the output from the listagg operation will be `20,40,50,60,70` so after the NULL value all sensor's data will be reported wrong!  Correct that by using this:

```
replace(LISTAGG( nvl(to_char(ColumnA), ','), ',' ) 
        WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ColumnB ), ',,,',',,')
```

Now your output is `20,,40,50,60,70`, keeping test_sensor2's NULL value and the rest in proper position.

HOWEVER now there is another problem in that the regex of the form `'[^,]+'` causes the same issue!  So even though the listagg output is fixed, the parsed output is back to being off after the column with the NULL value!  There is a different form shown below that fixes this problem.  Here is an example set up so you can comment/uncomment to see the differences as the data is processed.  Always expect the unexpected!

```
with TableA ( ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC ) AS (
  SELECT 20, 'A', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, 'B', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- make NULL
  SELECT 40, 'C', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 50, 'D', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 60, 'E', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 70, 'F', 'Z12345' FROM DUAL
),
tbl_tmp as (
  SELECT ColumnC,
         -- Preserve the NULL in position 2
         replace(LISTAGG( nvl(to_char(ColumnA), ','), ',' ) 
                 WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ColumnB ), ',,,',',,')
           AS test_sensor
  FROM   TableA
  GROUP BY ColumnC
)
--select * from tbl_tmp;
-- regex of format [^,]+ does not handle NULLs
SELECT ColumnC,
--       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '[^,]+', 1, 1) AS test_sensor1,  
--       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '[^,]+', 1, 2 ) AS test_sensor2,
--       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '[^,]+', 1, 3 ) AS test_sensor3,
--       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '[^,]+', 1, 4 ) AS test_sensor4
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS test_sensor1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1 ) AS test_sensor2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1 ) AS test_sensor3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( test_sensor, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1 ) AS test_sensor4
FROM  tbl_tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using your LISTAGG data and SubStr() and InStr() functions for separation:

```sql
WITH      --  Sample Data:
    tbl (COL_A, COL_B, COL_C) AS
        (   Select 20, 1, 'Z12345' From Dual Union All
            Select 30, 2, 'Z12345' From Dual Union All
            Select 40, 3, 'Z12345' From Dual Union All
            Select 50, 4, 'Z12345' From Dual Union All
            Select 60, 5, 'Z12345' From Dual Union All
            Select 70, 6, 'Z12345' From Dual Union All
            Select 90, 1, 'Z56789' From Dual Union All
            Select 80, 2, 'Z56789' From Dual Union All
            Select 70, 3, 'Z56789' From Dual 
        ),
  sensor_list AS    -- Your LISTAGG select - with added commas before and after list
    ( Select    COL_C,
                ',' || LISTAGG(COL_A, ',') WITHIN GROUP (Order By COL_B) || ',' "TEST_SENSOR" -- comma added before and after list
      From        tbl
      Group By  COL_C 
    )
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select  COL_C, 
        SubStr(TEST_SENSOR, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 1) + 1, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 2) - InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 1) - 1) "TEST_SENSOR_1",
        SubStr(TEST_SENSOR, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 2) + 1, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 3) - InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 2) - 1) "TEST_SENSOR_2",
        SubStr(TEST_SENSOR, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 3) + 1, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 4) - InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 3) - 1) "TEST_SENSOR_3",
        SubStr(TEST_SENSOR, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 4) + 1, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 5) - InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 4) - 1) "TEST_SENSOR_4",
        SubStr(TEST_SENSOR, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 5) + 1, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 6) - InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 5) - 1) "TEST_SENSOR_5",
        SubStr(TEST_SENSOR, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 6) + 1, InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 7) - InStr(TEST_SENSOR, ',', 1, 6) - 1) "TEST_SENSOR_6"
From sensor_list
--
--  R e s u l t:
--  COL_C   TEST_SENSOR_1  TEST_SENSOR_2  TEST_SENSOR_3  TEST_SENSOR_4  TEST_SENSOR_5  TEST_SENSOR_6
--  ------  -------------  -------------  -------------  -------------  -------------  -------------
--  Z12345  20             30               40             50               60             70
--  Z56789  90             80               70
```

If there is a possibility for null values you should handle that too (as described in Gary_W's answer)...
The above code works for up to 6 members of the list - if you need more just follow the same logic adding more columns to the main sql.